# how to delete file that is not on the server using PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering if I can delete file that is not on the server using PHP

For Example C:\Documents and Settings\a.txt, when the user provides the path?

Comment: You can't. PHP runs on the server, it can't do anything on the client machine. And Javascript can't delete files.

Comment: Delete from where? The user's computer?

Comment: You cant. You can ask the user for deleting the file.

Comment: This is not allowed to delete a local file using server side script. Think if its allowed someone will run the script and it deletes all files from c and you are screwed.

Comment: Better option is, to make a batch file.

Comment: you can use "unlink(filename,context)" function of php..

Comment: @Priyajain, yeah - on the server, eg local files for your script

Comment: @all i mean like this:a user wants to upload a music file to my website he will give the path or select the file.After the upload is successful the website ask him if he wants to keep the old file(i.e the file on his PC) if the answer is no the website should delete that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.
It would be a security nightmare if this would be possible.
Imagine that every website could delete every file on your local computer. PHP runs on the server and the file is local. When you upload a file to a website then PHP is able to process that file because the browser sends the file to the server that runs the webserver with PHP.